# How to make this bounce effect with jquery?

Tags: bounce

I want to make the same bounce but with jquery not css3.

I have tried the code in this example but the animation seems not quite the same that i'm looking for.

This is the example i tried:

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
  doBounce($('#bounce'), '10px', 500);   
}, 500);
    

function doBounce(element, distance, speed) {
  element
    .animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
    .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
}
```

```css
#bounce {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="bounce">Button</a>
```

And this is what i'm looking for as a bouncing arrow :[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp)

Best
Mohamed

Comment: Hi Mohamed - what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is a good place to find answers to technical problems you encounter in the course of a task, but not a good place to ask for help if you haven't even started the task.

Comment: Hi Vince, 
I have tried this code, but it didn't give me the same effect of bouncing:
`code`
setInterval(function(){ 
  doBounce($('#bounce'), '10px', 500);   
}, 500);
    

function doBounce(element, distance, speed) {
  element
    .animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
    .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
}`code`

Comment: Hi Mohamed; adding the code is useful, but it would be better if you edited your question to include it there. If all the information is in the question, then anybody can read it and easily understand everything about the issue; it is harder to understand if the reader has to go through the comments to find everything.

Answer (score 0):

You must try http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Use the source code example and then if you are not able to do. we can help.

Comment: Thank you Piara, but i'm not a jquery specialist this why i wanted someone  who can help to make my code more close to the animation that i focus on.

Comment: @MohamedMasmoudi you could probably try and follow that 30 days to jquery by Jeffrey way. That is the best tutorials to get you started and he also shows all the animation and how you can work with that in Jquery.